# Who is responsible for showing the SVProgressHud when show method called?

Tags: ios, svprogresshud

anywhere we can call SVProgress.show() to show the progress but specifically from where the progress presented ? who is responsible to display it? is the root view controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you noticed in iOS developing, all our view controllers are presented or pushed to another view controller. But our main viewcontroller is presented on window of our app. same way if we are adding someview onto window, it will be independent from any viewcontroller. By the same way, any PregressView are presented onto window of our app.

Comment: Ok, but who did you know that the progress will be presented onto the app's window , and the show() method has been implemented this way?